# replacing a new interface with old one in tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I've created a class that has a function called mainScreen(). It simply prints the main screen with two buttons on it. If you press any button, it must go to another function called signup(). I want to clear the whole frame and create new widgets but I can't clear the widgets

```
class graphics:
    def __init__(self, master):
    self.root = master


    def mainscreen(self):
        helv36 = tkFont.Font(family='Century Gothic', size=20)
        mainFrame = Frame(self.root)
        mainFrame.config(relief='sunken', width=1280, height=720, bg='light 
blue')
        mainFrame.pack(expand='yes', fill='both')
        inButton = Button(mainFrame, text = "Sign up", bd = 10, relief = 
GROOVE, font = helv36)
        inButton.bind("<Button-1>", self.signup)
        inButton.place(bordermode = OUTSIDE, width =160, height = 60, x = 
600, y = 300)
        upButton = Button(mainFrame, text = "Sign in", bd = 10, relief = 
GROOVE, font = helv36)
        upButton.bind("<Button-1>", self.signup)
        upButton.place(bordermode = OUTSIDE, width =160, height = 60, x = 
600, y = 400)
        mainFrame.pack_propagate(FALSE)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def signup(self,event):
        signUpShow = Frame(self.root)
        signUpShow.config(relief='sunken', width=1280, height=720, bg='light 
yellow')
        signUpShow.pack(expand='yes', fill='both')
```

Comment: why can't you clear the widgets? What's preventing you from doing that?

Comment: As in the bind function, the hold is being passed to another function singup() and I can't access the mainFrame variable from signup() as it is local to mainScreen()

Answer (score 0):

You `__init__` needs to have its code indented and it needs a call to `mainscreen`.  The solution to `mainFrame` being local within `mainscreen` is to make it also an attribute.

```
self.mainframe = mainFrame = Frame(self.root)
```

Then you can access `self.mainframe` within `signup`.